# Spark SQL Datediff between columns in minutes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 columns in a table (both dates, formatted as string type). I need to find difference between them in minutes and then average the difference over an year.

Format as below:
Requesttime: 11/10/2019 03:10:15 PM
Respondtime: 11/10/2029 03:20:10 PM

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can register a user defined function 

import datetime
def min_diff(a,b):
  start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
  end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(b,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
  return (end_time-start_time).total_seconds()/60
def year(c):
  return datetime.datetime.strptime(c,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%Y')
spark.udf.register(name='min_diff',f=lambda a,b:min_diff(a,b))
spark.udf.register(name='year', f=lambda c:year(c))
spark.sql('select avg(min_diff(start_time,end_time)) avg_time_diff, year(start_time) year from test_table group by year').show()
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for UDF. Just use spark sql functions as below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['11/10/2019 03:10:15 PM','11/10/2019 03:20:10 PM']
]).toDF('Requesttime','Respondtime')

df = df.withColumn(
    'diff_minutes',
    (F.to_timestamp('Respondtime', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').cast('bigint') -
     F.to_timestamp('Requesttime', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').cast('bigint')) / 60
)

df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|Requesttime           |Respondtime           |diff_minutes     |
+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|11/10/2019 03:10:15 PM|11/10/2019 03:20:10 PM|9.916666666666666|
+----------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

If you want to average the difference over a year, you can do

```
df.groupBy(
    F.year(F.to_timestamp('Requesttime', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')).alias('year')
).agg(F.avg('diff_minutes'))
```